# Blob URL generation confusion

Tags: javascript, java, html, bloburls

I am using the following piece of code to generate blob URL for an image:

```
1) let arrayBufferView =  new Int8Array(this.response); 
    let blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {type : 'image/png'});
    let img = document.querySelector('img');
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.onload = function() {URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);}
```

The JSON response is from a Java code which sends byte representation of image binary data. Byte in Java is 8-bit signed int. SO line 1 works fine
But when I replace line 1 with `let arrayBufferView =  new Uint8Array(this.response);` it still works fine. How will the 8bit signed from Java gets converted to Uint8Array (which is a 8 bit unsigned array view).

Then I tried the code with other variations of ArrayBuffer which are below:

```
let arrayBufferView =  new Int16Array(this.response);
let arrayBufferView =  new Uint16Array(this.response);
let arrayBufferView =  new Int32Array(this.response);
let arrayBufferView =  new Uint32Array(this.response);
```

For the above four ArrayBuffer the blob URL does not get generated and also why does it work for `let arrayBufferView =  new Uint8Array(this.response)`.

My understanding of blob URL is that byte representation sent from server is reconstructed by Blob constructor and the array buffer should correctly byte array sent from server. Then why does the `Uint8Array` work fine, but not `Int16Array, Uint16Array, Int32Array and Uint32Array`?

Comment: What is the type of `this.response`?

Comment: it is a json response

Comment: Is it an array of numbers? What kind of json data is it?